# SSL read: errno -12192

Tags: php, ssl-certificate

I am getting error "SSL read:errno-12192"

Actually previous my programming was working fine but past 1 week I was getting error:

> SSL error: SSL_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERT_ALERT

I then replaced my .pem file with new certificate and after replacing it I am getting 'SSL read: errno -12192'error.  My code as below:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  getcwd().'/ca.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/apna_generic_json.pem');
curl_easy_setopt(s, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,'/apna.pem'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: Please help me on this issue ASAP.